# Switch beetween multi select and select box

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This might seem like a strange one but is it possible to remove multiple from a html select box using javascript if it detects that it's a mobile browser?

```
<select id="plan" name="plan" multiple>
```

Comment: Use `removeAttr("multiple")`

Comment: The question you've written is the _opposite_ of the title. You probably want to change the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. `HTMLSelectElement` has a `multiple` property that you can manipulate.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  const selectEl = document.querySelector('select')
  selectEl.multiple = !selectEl.multiple
})
```

```html
<button>Toggle Multiple</button>
<br>
<select multiple>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

You could also manipulate the attribute instead of the property:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  document.querySelector('select').toggleAttribute('multiple')
})
```

```html
<button>Toggle Multiple</button>
<br>
<select multiple>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

How to detect a mobile browser is a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser).